# How to add user input automatically in alias in zshrc?

Tags: linux, zshrc

Is it possible to add the user input automatically while adding an alias and the command is expecting an input?

For example:

I am adding a alias to automatically open root prompt

```
alias rooter="sudo -i"
```

It then ask the user to input password so I am trying to automate it if any possible way is there even with the `function` but I do not know how to force ***alias*** to run the function when called

Comment: `alias rooter="sudo -i "` ?

Comment: Exactly what are you trying to automate? If you're trying to automate entering the password, please don't; it's hopelessly insecure.

Comment: Use sudoers to setup login without password. Do not ever store password in plain text in your shell configuration.

Comment: @kalalua : Why is this tagged _bash_? There is nothing related to bash in the question. You ask specifically about .zshrc, so it must be about zsh.

Comment: Hey guys thanks for your concerns and suggestion. After being a security analyst for such a long time m pretty sure about what I am doing. Well as @KamilCuk I tried /etc/sudoers but there I can not find any way to add this specific command **sudo -i** neither **/usr/bin/su** is working,  i still get password prompt

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the command accepts stdin for input, you can simply pipe into or use `<<<`, for instance

```
alias foo="bar <<<Howdy"
```

With `sudo`, you would need to ensure first that `sudo` reads from stdin:

```
alias rooter='sudo -S -i <<<DONT_MEMORIZE_ME_I_AM_THE_ROOT_PASSWORD'
```

Of course, who would want to write his root password in plain text into a file? .......

Comment: No @user1934428 I tried this but its not working. Any other suggestion????

Comment: It is treating the password after *here-string* as a different command

Comment: This is no a here-string. Which zsh are you using (i.e. what does a `echo $ZSH_VERSION` say?)?

Comment: Before testing this with `sudo`, replace `sudo -S -i` by a simple `cat`, which just should output the string to stdout. If this does not work either, there is a problem with your zsh and we have to tackle this. If the `cat` works, but the `sudo -Si` does not, there is a problem with your `sudo`  version. In any case, leave out the alias for the time being, because we need to fix the command itself first.